2022: a year in moderation

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year.
As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.
So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Italian Language over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community¹




Answer flags handled
37
3


Answers flagged
1
39


Comment flags handled
11
4


Comments deleted⁷
32
90


Comments flagged
0
15


Comments undeleted
1
0


Posts bumped
0
24


Posts deleted⁶
35
23


Posts undeleted
3
1


Question flags handled⁵
11
0


Questions closed
9
0


Questions flagged⁵
2
9


Questions protected
0
2


Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue
2
8


Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue
11
31


Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue
16
19


Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue
6
9


Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue
2
7


Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue
2
2


Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue
18
20


Users destroyed³
1
0


Users suspended²
0
17



Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Italian Language without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2021: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^
